# Why is GCC wrongly detecting shift count overflow?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, constexpr

I am trying to make a compile-time set of tags at most 8 chars out of constant string. For example, "abc" should become 0x6162630000000000, "" should become 0, etc.

For this, I thought I should use the fact that references to arrays do not decay to pointers and I can capture the N (size) of the const array with this:

```
template <size_t N>
inline constexpr uint64_t make_tag(char const (&arr)[N]) {
    if (N == 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    uint64_t result = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; (i < (N-1)) && (i<8); i++) {
        result = (result << 8) | arr[i];
    }

    if ((N-1) < 8) {
        result = result << (8 * (8 - (N-1)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

The N is captured correctly which is 1 for "" and len+1 for the rest of strings.

Here is the thing that confuses me: when doing something like

```
static constexpr uint64_t a0=make_tag("");
```

GCC 11.2 is telling me this:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'constexpr uint64_t make_tag(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned int N = 1; uint64_t = long unsigned int]':
<source>:24:43:   required from here
<source>:17:33: error: left shift count >= width of type [-Werror=shift-count-overflow]
   17 |                 result = result << (8 * (8 - (N-1)));
      |                          ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

clang does not behave like that.

For convenience, here is the [compiler explorer snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/r7P66n6jr):

EDIT: `if (N == 1) {...} else {...}` did the trick as @Useless suggested

Comment: tried changing `if` to `if constexpr ... else`?

Comment: Shifting 64 on a 64-bit integer is UB.

Comment: If `N` is supposed to never be larger than `8`, then you might want to add a `static_assert` to really make sure no one in the future comes along and uses a too large value. It will also help you simplify the first loop condition, since then you won't need the `i < 8` check, as the `static_assert` guarantees it.

Comment: Are you asking why `left shift count >= width of type` or why GCC complains about it?

Comment: I think you're expecting the compiler to take your first conditional into account, but it doesn't.

Comment: Then presumably the first conditional should be `if constexpr`

Comment: tested with `if constexpr`. It does not help

Comment: Note that this is just a warning (that you chose to turn into an error with -Werror). Constexpr evaluation properly skipped that instruction. However, gcc still instantiates the whole function, sees `<<64` and warns about it. Unwanted warnings about dead code are pretty common with compilers. Some static analysis tools are a bit better at it, but it is still heuristics with a balance between false positives and false negatives.

Comment: `if constexpr` will not stop a compiler giving warnings.    The behaviour is undefined if you do too large a bitshift, so the compiler is not obliged to give any diagnostics about that (part of the definition of undefined behaviour is "no diagnostic required").    The fact you have turned on additional warnings, and gotten a warning, indicates a potential concern.  The fact that the warning is not a diagnostic required by the standard means that the way to stop those warnings (beyond completely removing the offending statement) is up to the implementation (i.e. the compiler).

Comment: *Why is GCC wrongly detecting shift count overflow?*  It isn't, it is correctly detecting a wrong shift count overflow.  Shifting a 64-bit int by 64 is **undefined behavior** on any compiler.  Nice that GCC detected the mistake.  But it's not a standard requirement that the compiler detects that mistake, because sometimes it's a runtime only situation and sometimes it is hard to detect at compile time.  So both GCC and clang are behaving in compliance with the standard.

Comment: Minor point: you don't need parentheses around the conditions in that `for` loop. Just write `for (size_t i = 0; i < N-1 && i < 8; i++)`. The `&&` operator deliberately has a lower precedence that pretty much anything else.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Oh but I do. The compiler does not, but I do :)

Comment: @Eljay: Not in complete agreement with you. Eliminating that initial condition from the explanation does make the next code a mistake, indeed. But the hard cold fact is that the condition is there, with an early return. The code must make sense as a whole. You can take many legit functions and when you start looking at their "organs" (middle snippets) they do not make sense at all. Same situation here: that guard was there to let the compiler know that edge case was caught. It did not pay attention to it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is GCC wrongly detecting shift count overflow?

It isn't.

When `N=1`, the code

```
    if ((N-1) < 8) {
        result = result << (8 * (8 - (N-1)));
    }
```

results in a 64-bit shift.

If you don't want that code compiled for `N=1`, make it explicit:

```
    if (N > 1 && (N-1) < 8) {
        result = result << (8 * (8 - (N-1)));
    }
```

---

Putting everything inside the `else` branch of the initial check `if (N ==1) { return 0; } else { ...` works too.

It's unclear why GCC doesn't propogate the constraint on `N` implied by the early return without that, but I suspect it's simply not required.

Note the standard language around `if constexpr` says:

> If the value of the converted condition is false, the first substatement is a discarded statement, otherwise the second substatement, if present, is a discarded statement.

There's nothing there about statically discarding anything *after* the `if constexpr` statement, even if the taken branch has an early return. Of course it could be optimized out, but it still needs to be compilable in the first place.

Comment: there is an early return at the beginning of the function. It should not reach there

Comment: if/else worked. But that's not really nice.

Comment: Honestly, being explicit at the point of use is normally better than accumulating implied constraints and expecting humans to keep track of them.

Comment: @Useless: Is a matter of how one's brain was trained to reason about the code, and the style. I myself, for example, like the early return and think in terms of "If I've got here, everything is fine". Endless nesting is so annoying for my taste. But that's just me. Despite the flavors used by ppl, I believe GCC is having a minor bug in this case.

Comment: I like having sanity checks & early returns at the top when it makes it easy to reason about things ("if I reached here, I know this object is sane and usable"), but not so much when it makes it hard to reason about things ("if I reached here, I know N is an odd power of 3 and less than M which must be divisible by 7"). The distinction probably depends on context.

Comment: @Useless: I agree with you, and testing if a string is empty is common sense to be at the beginning of the function. Is nowhere near how you have explained as convoluted. But I do agree with you on that one, no arguments there. This case tho, not so much.